# mysql insert on duplicate FIELD instead of KEY

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates, field

```
-------------------------------------
| user_id | user_name | user_visits |
-------------------------------------
| 1       | foo       | 5           |
-------------------------------------
| 2       | bar       | 12          |
-------------------------------------
```

**user_id: auto increament, user_visits: default 1**

INSERT INTO table (user_name) VALUES ('baz'), ('bar'), ('qux');

the above statement will of course insert 3 new records, as the result:

```
-------------------------------------
| user_id | user_name | user_visits |
-------------------------------------
| 1       | foo       | 5           |
-------------------------------------
| 2       | bar       | 12          |
-------------------------------------
| 3       | baz       | 1           |
-------------------------------------
| 4       | bar       | 1           |
-------------------------------------
| 5       | qux       | 1           |
-------------------------------------
```

but what I'm trying to achieve is:

```
-------------------------------------
| user_id | user_name | user_visits |
-------------------------------------
| 1       | foo       | 5           |
-------------------------------------
| 2       | bar       | 13          |
-------------------------------------
| 3       | baz       | 1           |
-------------------------------------
| 4       | qux       | 1           |
-------------------------------------
```

so literally,

if field user_name exists, update user_visits, else insert a new record.

is it possible to achieve this with a single insert statement?

Answer (score 6):

Sure there is but it has nothing to do with your `insert` statement.  You need to add a unique index on the `user_name` column:

```
create unique index user_name_idx on yourtable (user_name);
```

Then afterward in your code that tracks the count will have to decide whether to do an insert or an update.

Answer (score 6):

You have to create a key for your username field and then use **`INSERT ON DUPLICATE`** query to update the columns values.

For example your query must be,

```
   INSERT INTO table (user_name) VALUES ('baz'), ('bar'), ('qux') 
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user_visits=user_visits+1;
```

For further reference visit http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: ok but if need compare with 2 key like: agency and user_name prevent new row and update instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could leave your INSERT statement as is and implement a trigger that handles your special actions.

See: [An Introduction To Triggers](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i)